# Select Only one row per user and date

Tags: sql, linq

i want to select only one row per user and date

so if the data like this

```
ID  User    Date
25  3597    2014-09-04 13:37:12.953
26  2100    2014-09-04 13:37:29.820
27  3597    2014-09-04 13:38:12.953
28  2100    2014-09-04 13:38:29.820
29  3597    2014-09-05 13:40:12.953
30  2100    2014-09-05 13:40:29.820
```

the result should be 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The result should be `4`

If all you need is the count, in SQL, you can use `COUNT(DISTINCT)`, like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT User, Date) FROM MyTable
```

In LINQ, you can use `GroupBy` followed by `Count`:

```
int cnt = src.Items.GroupBy(item => new {i.User, i.Date}).Count();
```